# What would you call the "neutral" variety in a range of food products?

Tags: terminology, food

Imagine you are naming a range of packaged, vegan, meat-like pan-fry kebab products that come with different marinades. There's a Curry, a [Döner Kebab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doner_kebab), and a [Gyro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyro_(food)).

The final product of the range comes with no marinade or spices at all - it is "neutral".

Is there a common term in English that can be applied to a food product that is "neutral" in this sense?

Comment: Maybe *plain* would work?

Comment: @Matt "plain" is great! I worry a little bit that it could be taken as too negative, but I think it's the word I was looking for, do put it as an answer

Comment: Unspiced or unflavored or flavor-ready™ :)

Comment: @Tim lol, that would probably totally work for the American market! Nice!

Comment: @Pekka "Plain" is not seen as negative in foodstuffs, especially when compared with other varieties. Think yogurt: I can buy vanilla, strawberry, low-fat, or plain. Plain isn't any better or worse, it just hasn't had anything done to it.

Comment: _Natural_? It's what I've seen as the marketing term for plain potato crisps and other "neutral" products.

Answer (score 3):

**unseasoned** (*adj.*):

(of food) not flavoured with salt, pepper or other spices

> '*The dish is unseasoned, the pepperiness supplied by the rocket and the saltiness by the prosciutto.*'

Source: [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com)

Comment: But adding rocket and prosciutto (or other non-spice, non-salts or non-pepper) seems to contradict the OP's idea of "no marinades or spices at all"...

Comment: @oerkelens I take the ODO's sentence as saying no additional spices are added to the dish, aside from those already in the the base ingredients.